# I'm trying to make an iterative jQuery scrolling animation that scrolls through multiple instances of the same div class, pausing in between

Tags: jquery, animation, settimeout, scrolltop, iteration

The way this function will work:

**1)** The user clicks the button with ID "surf" and the animation begins

**2)** The function finds the first instance of div with class "threadboard," pauses there for 1.5 seconds, then smoothly scrolls down to the next instance of a div with class "threadboard," pauses there for 1.5s and then scrolls smoothly to the next, and so on

**3)** The function should do this through all the instances of divs with class "threadboard," and then end

I'm trying to use jQuery with the methods `scrollTop()`, `each()`, `animate()` and `setTimeout()` so far with mixed success. Here's what I have so far (**EDIT:** to include working but imperfect code):

```js
var currentIndex = 0;
var numDivs = 18;

$(window).load(function() {
    $('#surf').click(
        function(){start();}
    );
});

function start() {
//if (numDivs > 0) {
    var winY = window.screenY;
            $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 225 * currentIndex}, 1100);
    //
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % numDivs;
    setTimeout(start, 3000);
//}
}
```

Right now I realize I'm kindof using a bootleg method by estimating that each instance is a certain number of pixels apart, and have hard-coded in the number of instances, which isn't ideal. What is the best way to write this function? The code will be implemented at http://cornellhub.com/board/

Comment: The key piece you're missing is `sending the position of the element to the function, to allow it to control the scrolling`. you need to `place your iterator within your event (the surf click)`, then grab the `position of the element with position.top` and `send it as a variable to the function`. You can see a great example of that below in my answer, with the winY variable.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy had the right methodology, and with a bit of troubleshooting we found a solution that worked for everyone. See below for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my shot:

http://jsfiddle.net/3aBx9/

Basically, I check the top position of every existence of `.threadboard`, iterate over each one, add a value to the timer and let it run.

Creating a cancel button should be as simple as `clearTimeout()`.

**Final edit by original poster, with code modified that works in all browsers.** The ultimate solution was to use `body, html` instead of either `body` or `html`, the former which works in webkit browsers and the latter which works in non-webkit browsers. The function and timeout also had to be moved out of the scope of the `$(document).ready(function () {`. The code below now reflects the edited solution:

```
var timeOut = 1500;

function startSurf(winY) {
//new timeout function
setTimeout(function () {
    //the page neesd to be animated (relative of course, careful)
    $('body').animate({

        //animate the scroll
        scrollTop: winY

        //scroll speed
    }, 'fast');

    //our timer needs to be declared outside the functin so it doesn't just jump to the end.
}, timeOut);

//add 1.5 seconds for each iteration loop or it will try to jump to the end.
timeOut += 1500;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#surf').click(function () {
    var numThreads = $('.threadboard');

    $.each(numThreads, function (index, obj) {
        //the position of the object
        var position = $(obj).position();

        //the top position of the object (relative of course, careful)
        var winY = position.top;

        //on the first iteration
        if (index == 0) {
            $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: winY
            }, 'fast');

            //for every iteration after
        } else {
            startSurf(winY);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: I went and tried to implement your method, and couldn't get any result. In the meantime, however, I did write another function that does the job, but again imperfectly and with some global variables and things hard-coded in. Let's see if we can bridge the two ideas and get something to work! I'll add the semi-working code to the original post:

Comment: @wnajar no problem - I've got an idea of what you need anyway, I'll get back shortly with a solution to your issue.

Comment: @wnajar Please sett my updated code. as explained, I've copy and pasted this into Firebug and ran it. It scrolls to the top of each `.threadboard` every 1.5 seconds. please let me know if this is not what you want.

Comment: it's missing the click handler now, and the implementation. So we could still use `$(window).load(function() {
        $('#surf').click(
  function(){startSurf(winY);}
    );
});` but how are we going to pass the winY parameter? I pasted your code into the Chrome console and it finds the expected .threadboards but there is no code execution, click handling or scrolling. Thoughts? Not sure if I'm just missing something here...

Comment: I didn't add the event to anything because I wanted to give you an option. I can't see a '#surf' on the page. If you simply paste the code I provided to you, inside of $('#surf').click(function(){ `code I pasted goes here` });, then click on the `#surf` element, this will work as described.

Comment: You can also see your implementation live on the website: http://cornellhub.com/board/

Click the blue surf button up top, doesn't do anything. No click handling or code execution. I'll leave it up for now. @Ohgodwhy

Comment: @wnajar - Okay...there you go, all I've done this time is add the `$('#surf').click(function(){});` to the same code as the original post. This works just like you want in all major browsers, including Chrome *snicker*

Comment: At the risk of sounding like an idiot, I've done just that @Ohgodwhy and no action... the code seems right but it doesn't work?

Comment: Do you have it wrapped in a document.ready function? like `$(function(){`, or `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: I really don't know what's up here but I've done just that and tested it in Chrome Dev, Aurora, Safari and IE9 (lol, just for fun) and no beans. Click the blue surf button, nothing. I read through the code and understand what's going on but something doesn't seem to work. You can see the code in lines 55-95 in http://cornellhub.com/static/javascript/hubjs-board.js. The #surf element is at the top of the page in blue. @Ohgodwhy

Comment: It's wrapped up in a `$(window).load(function() {` @Ohgodwhy

Comment: I don't see anything relating to the code I've posted in that JS file you linked.

Comment: Lines 54-98 in [link](http://cornellhub.com/static/javascript/hubjs-board.js), if you don't see it updated try a Ctrl+F5 to clear your cache.

Comment: Okay, I see it now. But more over, I just checked with the same browsers as mentioned and it works out of the box as you have it now.

Comment: I don't know how else to say this but if you click the blue "surf" button with the "surf" tag, it definitely doesn't work in any browser. Could a third party try to verify this?

Comment: :( I'd like to provide more insight, but i've checked from multiple boxes, multiple OS's, multiple browsers, standards compliant browsers support the feature, smartphones..I'm at a loss anymore, good luck brother.

Comment: Update @Ohmygod, at this point I've got it to work in Firefox Aurora 14.0a2, and IE9 but not my main browser, Chrome Dev 21.0.1145.0. Clearing all cache to check again, this may be a browser issue. At this point, however, Chrome is the most important as over 60% of site visitors use Chrome, and Firefox and IE9 have small minorities.

Comment: Cleared Chrome cache entirely, no beans. This solution works in Firefox and IE9, but seems to have trouble in Webkit-based browsers which unfortunately have a majority market share. Not sure of the reason. @Ohmygodwhy

Comment: Righto, the problem is that we were using the `HTML` element in the jQuery selector. We need to change that element to be `BODY` instead of `HTML`. We also need to move the function `AND` the `var timeOut = 1500;` out of the scope of the `$(document).ready function`